# "not all control paths return a value" in a function

Tags: c, return-value

As the title says, a function I want to use gets this warning. I want my function to find the address of the struct, among those with an equal or smaller `.d` value than the `distance` given to the function, that has a string field that is "smaller" in comparison with the given string. (due to other factors, there are no repeats, so >= is equivalent to >).

I'm fairly sure that every if and else have their return (unless I'm THAT blind) and I simply do not know what else could cause this warning.

The struct the function is looking through:

```
typedef struct Fixer_t SpelChk_En;
struct Fixer_t
{
    char *word;
    int d;
    SpelChk_En *next;
};
```

The function:

```
/*
| Function: FindSpelPlace
| Action: Finds where to wedge the new entry
| Input: Speller first struct, distance and the word
| Returns: Address of the previous entry
*/
SpelChk_En *FindSpelPlace( SpelChk_En *speller , char *str , int distance )
{
    if( speller->d < distance )
    {
        if( speller->next->d < distance )
            return FindSpelPlace( speller->next , str, distance );
        else if( speller->next->d > distance )
            return speller;
        else
        {
            if( strcmp(speller->next->word , str ) > 0 )
                return speller;
            else
                return FindSpelPlace( speller->next , str , distance );
        }
    }
    else if( speller->d == distance )
    {
        if( strcmp( speller->word , str ) < 0 )
        {
            if( strcmp( speller->next->word , str ) < 0 )
                return FindSpelPlace( speller->next , str , distance );
            else
                return speller;
        }
        else
            return speller;
    }
    else
    {
        //this can happen only with the first speller
        return NULL;
    }
    //This turned out far bigger than I figured it would be...
}
```

Comment: Remove the last `else` and return `NULL`

Comment: I'm not getting this error when I compile this code on my system. Are you sure that this is the function that's missing a return?

Comment: @ViteFalcon- I think that compilers are smart enough to detect that at least one branch of the if/else will execute. I suspect that's not the issue.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @templatetypedef: it depends on his compiler and its version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
return NULL;
```

as the last statement to the function.

---

Or modify the functtion to have **one** exit point only:

```
SpelChk_En *FindSpelPlace(SpelChk_En *speller, char *str, int distance)
{
  SpelChk_En * result = NULL;

  if (speller->d < distance)
  {
    if (speller->next->d < distance)
      result = FindSpelPlace(speller->next, str, distance);
    else if (speller->next->d > distance)
      result = speller;
    else
    {
      if (strcmp(speller->next->word, str) > 0)
        result = speller;
      else
        result = FindSpelPlace(speller->next, str, distance);
    }
  }
  else if (speller->d == distance)
  {
    if (strcmp(speller->word, str) < 0)
    {
      if (strcmp(speller->next->word, str) < 0)
        result = FindSpelPlace(speller->next, str, distance);
      else
        result = speller;
    }
    else
      result = speller;
  }

  return result;
}
```

This way the code is

- more structured
- easier to understand
- better to maintain
- less error prone

in one word: **"better"**.

Comment: The OP's code, on my system, isn't generating this warning even with `-Wall` enabled. I'm fairly confident that the error isn't in the OP's code.

Comment: I would do the same and see what happens. Add return nullptr at the end.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Whether the comoiler issues or warning or not depends on which compiler is used.

Comment: That's a good point. I've just asked the OP what compiler they're using to see if that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure that 1 exit point is the right solution here.  You've turned a "not all paths return a value" problem - which the compiler can catch and warn you about into a "variable not assigned" problem - which the compiler will have a harder time with and will be more likely to blow up at runtime.

Comment: @PeteBaughman: My modifications of the code assumed the OP's code being complete and correct in it's context (which we do not know). However if these two assumptions stand, I see no issues with my modifcations to have one exit point, as the "*not all paths return a value*" warning obviously was a false alarm.

Comment: It may be all well and good, until some other developer comes along in six months and tweaks it.  Bugs that are caught by the compiler are cheaper to fix than bugs that are caught at runtime by the customer.

Comment: I would argue against the "easier to understand" bullet point.  If you see a line that assigns to `result`, you must scan over a lot of code to know that it is actually returned.